# SQL add data to two tables at once using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'd like to insert data into two tables, the second table being a foreign key (which is auto-incremented) using VB.

Here is my code so far...

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerUsername, CustomerAge, CustomerPassword)  " +
                   "VALUES (' " & txtusername.Text & " ' ,'" & txtage.Text & " ', '" & txtpassword.Text & " ')";
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Premier (CustomerID) FROM Customer.CustomerID";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My first INSERT works fine. Just not sure how to INSERT into the second table (as it is auto-incremented) and I am not using a textbox for the input.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can receive back the autoincrement value (A.K.A. IDENTITY) inserted in the first table with this query

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerUsername, CustomerAge, CustomerPassword) 
                  VALUES(@user, @age, @pass); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"

cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  txtusername.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtage.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
Dim idCustomer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

At this point is easy to add to the other table

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Premier (CustomerID) VALUES (@id)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idCustomer
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Notice how you can execute two commands together with the same call just separating them with a semicolon. Now, [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql)

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope

In alternative you can use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) with this syntax

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerUsername, CustomerAge, CustomerPassword) 
                  OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
                  VALUES(@user, @age, @pass)"
```

where ID is the name of the autoincrement column from your Customer table represented by the keyword INSERTED

But the most important thing that you should look at is how I have changed your query to use a parameterized approach. There are many reasons to do it in this way and you can find the most important one looking for [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). Other reasons are parsing problems (what if your user name contains a single quote?) or some simple errors like the one you have when you insert the name of your customer. Did you notice that you add a spurious space before and after the customer name?

Finally, a bit outside the scope, but you should also consider that storing passwords in clear text inside a database is a big security risk.

See [Best way to store passwords in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)