# How can I insert data in SQL server to two different tables while having a ORDER# primary key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, vb.net

I want to insert data on to two different tables in SQL server from VB.net.
I have Identity increment set up in SQL that is where the order# comes from. The rest of the data comes from vb.net. Another issue is that every time I capture an order, everything from the Order table copies to the Order Details table which causes a lot of unnecessary duplicated rows.
**Here is my current code in VB:**

```
   Private Sub btnGetTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetTotal.Click

    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("x")

    Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ordenes_5]([Sub_Total]) VALUES (@SubTotal)"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubTotal", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lbltotal.Text
    connection.Open()
    cmd.Connection = connection
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()

    Dim icmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("insert into ordenes_5_details (Orden#) select Orden# from Ordenes_5", connection)
    connection.Open()
    icmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()

    Dim command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Ordenes_5_details (Articulo, Cantidad, Precio) VALUES (@Articulo, @Cantidad, @Precio)"

    command.Parameters.Add("@Articulo", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Cantidad", SqlDbType.Int)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Precio", SqlDbType.Float)


    connection.Open()
    command.Connection = connection

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        command.Parameters(0).Value = If(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, DBNull.Value)
        command.Parameters(1).Value = If(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, DBNull.Value)
        command.Parameters(2).Value = If(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, DBNull.Value)


        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next

    MsgBox("se capturo en ambas tablas")
    connection.Close()


End Sub
```

**These are my results in SQL server:**

Order table. Orden# is the PRIMARY KEY in this table.

| Orden# | Sub_Total |
| --- | --- |
| 1015 | $11.28 |

Order details table. Orden# is a FOREIGN KEY.

| Orden# | Articulo | Cantidad | Precio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1015 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | BURRITO | 3 | 6.9 |
| NULL | COOKIE | 4 | 3.96 |

**This is what I'm looking for:**

Order table

| Orden# | Sub_Total |
| --- | --- |
| 1015 | $11.28 |

Order details table

| Orden# | Articulo | Cantidad | Precio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1015 | BURRITO | 3 | 6.9 |
| 1015 | COOKIE | 4 | 3.96 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL add data to two tables at once using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502696/sql-add-data-to-two-tables-at-once-using-vb-net)

Comment: `command.Parameters.Add("@Cantidad", SqlDbType.VarChar)` You have been told this is a problem; learn to parameterize properly. Your first INSERT is not parameterized at all. Develop good habits - write code consistently.

Comment: @SMor There I changed it just for you cause I appreciate you lookin out for us beginners.

Comment: @SMor I have been trying to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, I am getting this error : 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.' I am also now getting an extra row in my Order table. Orden# 1015 | Sub_total 11.28, Orden# 1016 | Sub_total 11.28. How do I implement it correctly?

Comment: It's inserting the extra row in order details because you're telling it to, `Dim icmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("insert into ordenes_5_details (Orden#) select Orden# from Ordenes_5", connection)`

Comment: Also, you probably want to avoid `float` in your currency columns as this will lead to errors in totals, ref: [float and real (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) _Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order/Order Detail pattern is quite common in database work so you need to become comfortable with it. There are several ways to deal with this. I will demonstrate one way.

You have already been cautioned in comments that the field in the database for currency amounts should be decimal.

Database objects like `Connection` and `Command` use unmanaged code. To release these resources, the architects of these libraries provide `Dispose` methods. .Net has provided vb.net with `Using...End Using` blocks to close and dispose objects. You can combine more than one object in a single Using block by using commas.

You can pass the `CommandText` and the `Connection` directly to the constructor of the Command. I have added an extra line to the first Insert statement. This is and output parameter. We add the parameter to the parameters collection and set the `Direction`. Retrieve the value after the `Command` is executed.

The second Insert can now add the field `Oden#` and a parameter, `@OrderID`, to the VALUES list. We set the `Value` to `NewOrderID` since it is the same for each execution of the Command.

Since I added a parameter, I changed the indexes of the `Parameters` in the `For` loop.

```
Private Sub btnGetTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetTotal.Click
    Dim sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ordenes_5]([Sub_Total]) VALUES (@SubTotal);
                Set @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
    Dim NewOrderID As Integer
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("x"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubTotal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(lbltotal.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        NewOrderID = CInt(cmd.Parameters("ID").Value)
    End Using

    sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Ordenes_5_details (Oden#, Articulo, Cantidad, Precio) VALUES (@OrderID, @Articulo, @Cantidad, @Precio)"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NewOrderID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Articulo", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cantidad", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Precio", SqlDbType.Decimal)
        cn.Open()
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            cmd.Parameters(1).Value = If(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, DBNull.Value)
            cmd.Parameters(2).Value = If(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, DBNull.Value)
            cmd.Parameters(3).Value = If(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, DBNull.Value)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("se capturo en ambas tablas")
End Sub
```